# Reverse Lexicographic Order

Tags: combinatorics

*Find the 233rd subset of [12] with five elements in reverse lexicographic
order.*

I am a little confused with the difference between normal and reverse lexicographic order. I think I understand that in lexicographic order. The first few subsets would look like this: {1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,6},...,{1,2,3,4,12},{1,2,3,5,6}, and so on.

In reverse lexicographic order, would the first few subsets simply be {5,4,3,2,1},{6,4,3,2,1},...,{12,4,3,2,1},{6,5,3,2,1}? i.e. the same only read from right to left.

(*Aside*) So then, since there are ${12 \choose 5}$=792 subsets of size 5, the 233rd subset in reverse lexicographic order would be equal to the 559th subset in normal lexicographic order?

Comment: [Possibly useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368526)

Comment: In reverse lexicographic order, the first few subsets would be $\{12,11,10,9,8\}$, $\{12,11,10,9,7\}$, $\{12,11,10,9,6\}$. Your aside is correct.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @Frentos: That’s not right, I’m afraid: see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to depend on the author quite heavily what reverse lexicographic order actually means. In Peter Cameron's *Combinatorics,* reverse lexicographic is simply lexicographic order, but with the word written backwards (reversed internal order). However, [oeis](http://oeis.org/wiki/Orderings) says that reverse lexicographic order is the lexicographic list written backwards (reversed external order). What the question means by reverse lexicographic order will decide how to actually answer the question.

Comment: Thank you, it appeared that my author's 'version' of reverse lexicographical order is also called colexicographical order. So if we had a subset of size 3 from [6], then the first few subsets would be: {1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{1,2,5}, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What **Frentos** wrote in the comments is incorrect. The [reverse lexicographical order](https://oeis.org/wiki/Orderings#Reverse_lexicographic_order) on subsets of $[12]$ with five elements is found by pretending that $12<11<10<\ldots<3<2<1$ and using the resulting lexicographical order. Thus, the first two are indeed $\{12,11,10,9,8\}$ and $\{12,11,10,9,7\}$, but the next one after that is $\{12,11,10,8,7\}$, not $\{12,11,10,9,6\}$.

This means that your aside is not correct. It would be *almost* correct if you were talking about the [reflected lexicographic order](https://oeis.org/wiki/Orderings#Reverse_lexicographic_order), which *is* simply the reversal of the usual lexicographic order: it would be off by one, since the $233$-rd element from the end of the lexicographical order is the $(79\color{red}3-233)$-rd, or $560$-th element, not the $559$-th element. Here’s a HINT for the correct approach: if $a<b<c<d<e$, compare the position of $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ in the lexicographic order with the position of $\{13-a,13-b,13-c,13-d,13-e\}$ in the reverse lexicographic order.