# Generate all N-bit numbers in such an order that the number of 1s increases monotonically

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

For a given positive integer $N$, is there an efficient algorithm to generate all $N$-bit numbers in such an order that the number of 1s in the binary representation increases monotonically?

Comment: Define efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate all $n$-bit numbers with $k$ ones, start out with the $k$ ones at the left, and in each step, move the right-most one that's followed by a zero to the right and move all ones following it right behind it; e.g.:

$$
11100,11010,11001,10110,10101,10011,01110,01101,01011,00111\;.
$$

You can keep a pointer to the $1$ that you're currently moving to the right, which also tells you how many ones to move to the left when this one can no longer move. For $k\gt n/2$, it will be more efficient to move the zeros instead of the ones.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368526) may also be helpful.

Comment: If you reverse this, it  seems to be a monotonic increasing code (alas only for the weight level). It is like $k$ soldiers (1's) passing a river (0's) one after another..

Comment: See also [pre-fascicle 3a](http://www.computing-wisdom.com/computingreadings/fasc3a.pdf) of Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*: "Generating All Combinations".

Comment: I expected this to be in Vol 4., because it is similar to monotonic Gray codes. My print copy is in the cellar. Need the ebook. :)

Comment: http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/ Combinatorial Algorithms: Part 1 .